# Digital subscription on Newspaper differs from paper version

Tags: navigation, content, news

We browse newspaper sites daily and find the news the editors find most readable determined by the editors. They decide how important a news is, how it should be presented to the audience. Those news are less dependent on dates, which works very well for the casual newspaper browsing experience.

But if you are a digital subscriber to the newspaper, you get the same view which means that you see yesterdays and even older news mixed with today’s news. Often there is no option (other than faced search) to see just the last 24 hours news in an editorial decided way. It’s just the list from your faceted search, or the dates mixed news view to see.

**Is there a reason why digital news doesn’t have that today news view for subscribers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tough question Benny.  I read an article a few years ago that talked about online papers versus hardcopy papers. It didn't answer your question unfortunately however it did make this interesting quote:

> The paper cites other researchers on the subject who have theorized that the layout of online pages—which often insert ads mid-story or force readers to click additional pages to finish the story—may alter the reading experience.

Most online newspapers from my experience have an aggregated landing page citing various news subjects.  The problem it creates is exactly what you have mentioned.  A page like that will capture the top 1 or 2 most recently published articles in that section and the issue with that is that a given article could have last been published 2 days ago in that section.

That's the closest I've experienced to what you are asking.  The link below is a prime example:

- http://www.myfamilyclub.co.uk/

[image: A poor example of focusing on not showing today's but only most recently published news]

Click on any link and view the published date (of the articles shown in the pictured example).  It's a common issue that I don't see being solved anytime soon for smaller or even larger online publishers.

For a better user experience there should be a way for the subscriber to customise their view or be a section with only today's news.  USAToday have managed the latter with an option to go fullscreen and focus in only on what is happening now:

- http://www.usatoday.com/
  [image: USA Today's good example of focusing on today's news]

Unless online publishing sites take a more measured and user centric approach to how they display their news (many have come a long way such as USA Today) then I believe we will always have this problem.

**Online resource reference:**

- http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/press_box/2011/08/print_vs_online.html

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two primary reasons for this:

### Historical

When news services started putting content online, they focused on the differentiating factors of online news services vs print services.  That meant focusing on up to the minute news rather than a curated selection of news which had been chosen to give a recap of the previous day's news.

### Differentiation

It was (and to an extent still is) difficult to get news organisations to adopt the internet, for fear that putting content online would reduce their circulation numbers and hurt their profit margins.  So the idea of putting something online that directly competed with their curated print media structure would have been a difficult choice to make.

---

Interestingly there are a few sites that do this, but none of them deal with "up to the minute news".  My favourite, and I think the best example, is the Economist.  However they only publish their print version once a week, and the digital version is an excellent mirror of the print version content for content (including adverts).

As the main issue with news becomes a question of how we filter the news coverage down to something suitable for each user, I believe more sites will tend towards offering this sort of content.  However don't expect them to drop the "up to the minute" coverage either, as each site wants to get that initial spike of traffic by covering the news first.